# htaccess rewrite rule redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I have some old urls

```
http://www.website.com/result/?q=&result=1
http://www.website.com/result/?q=&result=2
http://www.website.com/result/?q=&result=3
http://www.website.com/result/?q=&result=4
```

etc.. probably going up to about 60

Is there anyway I can create one rule that redirects any query that looks like this to the home page /home/ instead of my trying to redirect all of them individualy?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

yes, i suppose you are using apache HTTPD. In your server configuration you can define an regular expression which filter the pattern you want. For example:

```
<FilesMatch "/site/*">
...
</FilesMatch>
```

Define a RegExp and tell where to redirect or what to do.

Hope this helps, Cheers